DNS Setup for subdomain, 2 hosting companies, AWS hosted zone
I'm trying to set up a subdomain test.example.com that is hosted on AWS.  I have some assets hosted on DigitalOcean and some newer assets in AWS.

My domain DNS is setup with DigitalOcean's 3 nameservers as NS records.  (ie, I log into namecheap.com and set the "custom dns" to the 3 DigitalOcean nameservers)
In DigitalOcean I created 4 NS records with test.example.com pointing to the 4 AWS Namespace servers
In AWS I have a hosted zone.  example.com.  Under that I have A record for test.example.com that points to my API Gateway.

I know my AWS configuration is correct.  If I go to my hosting company and change the NS records from DigitalOcean to AWS, test.example.com works just fine.  What am I doing wrong here?   I thought it was DNS propagation that was taking a while but I've waited about 50 hours now.
Update
Example.com is just an example.  Not the real domain
My AWS resources are Terraform controlled.  So I want the Route53 routing controlled by Terraform -- so if my API gateway or whatever changes, I don't need to adjust DNS.  This is why I'm not going to DigitalOcean and setting up an A record for test.example.com to my AWS API Gateway.
So my thought with the NS records in DigitalOcean to AWS's NS servers -- test.example.com routes to DigitalOcean, the NS records point to AWS so DNS lookup is done in AWS, and is routed to test.example.com via my A record is Route53
I've tried changing the Hosted Zone in AWS to test.example.com with an A record to test.example.com but that setup didn't work either.

Your post is unclear.  Did you want to provide the actual domain for us to look at?  Also, why are you delegating NS to AWS servers rather then just controlling it all from DigitalOcean?   Lastly, what did the actual records look like?  (I wonder if you did the delegation correctly).

Seems like you need to add test.example.com as a hosted zone in route53, not example.com
